# Битрикс убрать оповещение "необходимо создать фасетный индекс для ускорения работы" после создания фасетного индекса через api

Tags: php, битрикс

Создаю фасетный индекс через [api D7](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/iblock/propertyindex/manager/index.php). Однако уведомление о необходимости перестройки фасетного индекса не пропадает:

[image: ведомление о необходимости перестройки фасетного индекса]

Как его убрать через api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За уведомление фасетного индекса в административной части отвечает метод [`Manager::checkAdminNotification($force = false)`](http://bxapi.ru/src/?id=264834)

Comment: Только сейчас добрался до ответа :) Для пояснения заглянувшим: нужно вызвать `\Bitrix\Iblock\PropertyIndex\Manager::checkAdminNotification();` после перестройки фасетного индекса, и уведомление пропадает.